# line is the perpendicular bisector of a segment obtained by reflecting twice through two rays

Tags: euclidean-geometry

Given two rays, L and M, with common origin O, and a point Q inside the acute angle formed by the rays, reflect Q across L to obtain Q' and then reflect Q' across M to obtain Q''.  Similarly, reflect Q across M to obtain P' and then reflect P' across L to obtain P''.
Show that the line through O and Q is the perpendicular bisector of the segment joining P'' and Q''.
How do you do this?
It is easy to show that Q and all reflected points lie on the circle with center O that passes through Q.  I thought of using reflection across the line through O and Q and then use a symmetry argument but couldn't see just how to implement this idea.
I would really appreciate any help. Thanks

[image]

Comment: It would help some of us if you could provide a picture.

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't provide a picture but I don't know how to do this using a programming language and as a new user I am not allowed to post images

Comment: @Emmad: I’ve taken the liberty of adding a diagram.

Comment: @Thanks Brian, this is helpful.

Comment: If P" and Q" lie on the premituer of a circle with O at the center, then if you draw 2 lines, OP" and OQ" these 2 lines would be equal (each is a radius of the same circle). From this the proof follows.

Answer (score -1):

Thanks Emmad. As you said, the result follows. The fact you mention combined with the following show that the triangles that need to be shown are congruent in fact are:
the angle Q''Q'Q equals the angle P''P'Q so the arcs they intercept are the same.
Thank you for your answer

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer